# Why do Microsoft put the "user can refund Windows or entire system on which Windows is installed" clause on their Windows 7 EULA?

Tags: windows

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_refund

Is it because

1. It's a ruling from the antitrust case (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Microsoft)
2. It's illegal in most countries (I'm especially interested in Australia)

Or both?

Comment: Obviously you didn't scroll to the 1000 citations on that article. . .